# Android Webview Client Certificate & Http authorization

Tags: android, ssl, webview, authorization, client-certificates

The last days i am trying to access a website through webview using client certificate. I used  the open source project from https://github.com/yonekawa/webview-with-client-certificate. Evertything works fine on android 2.3.3 platform, i can install the certificates and after ssl error invokes the

```
        onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
        SslError error){
                      handler.proceed();}
```

then

```
       onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(final WebView view,
        final HttpAuthHandler handler, final String host, final String realm)
```

is invoked and i can pass the credentials for a secure access.
The thing is that 4.x webview does not have the same behaviour.I had to create a custom jar with all the internal classes please see:https://github.com/yonekawa/webview-with-client-certificate/issues/1 so i can use the hiden method

```
      onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view,
        ClientCertRequestHandler handler, String host_and_port)
```

The problem is that the method gets overiden just fine and the project gets compiled , but the method never gets invoked, instead *onReceivedSslError* gets invoked like usual and then page finish loading with a white page without even invoke the *onReceivedHttpAuthRequest* like in 2.3.
Did anyone actually manage to make the above example work for a website that requires client certificate and authorization ?

Comment: Same thing i tried without any success.